# define model classes in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

currently I define my model classes in this way:

```
export class Company {
  constructor(
    public id?: number,
    public name?: string,
    public shortName?: string
  ) {}
}
```

The reason, why I use `?` is that in this case I don't get an error that values for properties aren't provided if I want to assign an empty `company` object to a variable like this:

```
this.editDataItem = new Company();
```

Can I somehow avoid the use of `?` in the model declaration? Or is this the right way if I want to assign an empty instance to a variable without declaring all the properties? Are there any best practices for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?` is just a shorthand for `undefined`.
To prevent a property being `undefined` you would need to set it on initialization either by passing values to the constructor or setting default values.

Depending on your use-case this is a perfectly valid and correct way to define a models property types.

You might as well change your class to:

```
export class Company {
  id?: number;
  name?: string;
  shortName?: string;

  constructor(
  ) {}
}
```

Now you still have public properties but they are `undefined` by default and there is no need to pass any values to the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do like this, It is in JS.

```js
class Company {
  constructor(
     id = 0,
     name = '',
     shortName = ''
  ) {}
}

const company1 = new Company();

console.log(company1);
```

In Typescript you can do this:

```
export class Company {
  constructor(
    public id: number = 0,
    public name: string = '',
    public shortName: string = ''
  ) {}
}

const company1 = new Company();

console.log(company1);
```

The above snippet will help you to set the default values even if they are not passed. It could be a better way to achieve this, `?` accepts `undefined` as value.

Comment: This may work, but ultimately defeats the purpose to easily check for *actual* data that's stored in the model. Now one has to check for `0` or an empty string, which both might be valid data.

Comment: Yes, this could be an issue only when user tries to send the same data as default, but gives better understanding for the field created in the Company object. What do you suggest?

Comment: My suggestion would be to move the optional values from the constructor as passable arguments over to a property definition. OP seems to want to use it as `new Company()` without passing it arguments. It really comes down to the use-case here :D

Comment: Yes, he should pass the options parameter as configurable which can give him more  power to handle all scenario in an efficient manner.